# ASUS laptop - wifi not connecting after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, asus, atheros

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and now cannot connect to wifi. If trying from system menu, I see "Connection failed - Activation of network connection failed". Wired connection is working. Network adapter is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 but driver is missing in "Software and Updates - Additional Drivers". Here is the wireless info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########
```

Report from: 19 Aug 2018 13:50

Booted last: 19 Aug 2018 00:00

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

kernel

Linux 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

desktop

Ubuntu

lspci

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCMCIA card info

rfkill

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lsmod

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
ath9k                 151552  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              471040  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
ath3k                  20480  0
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k
bluetooth             548864  34 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,ath3k,btusb
cfg80211              622592  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
wmi                    24576  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
video                  45056  2 asus_wmi,i915

interfaces

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Speedport_W_724V_09071602_00_008B

network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root       882     1  0 13:15 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F4328CE52BA6067DD4EDE7B
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath9k
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)
parm:           use_msi:Use MSI instead of INTx if possible (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     94213E6B06C24095311E862
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath9k_common
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     D5984DFEF6457DDB060988E
depends:        ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath9k_hw
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     555BBBB9D4FCA58A05E7C0D
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     36C0F7AEF3B569F1798216D
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath3k
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1CEA5CF286EDB289C1D0BF8
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D5B0789D4C423C81CCFB437
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

module parameters

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0
use_msi: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

/etc/modules

lp

coretemp

modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf]
options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

rc.local

echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] && numlockx on

[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] && numlockx on

echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] && numlockx on
rfkill unblock all

exit 0

pm-utils

udev rules

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.2 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
PCI device 0x168c:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

dmesg

[   35.228340] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   35.635028] r8169 0000:04:00.2 eth0: link down
[   35.635112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   35.652048] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 7 times)
[   38.421786] r8169 0000:04:00.2 eth0: link up
[   38.421806] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   39.035824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 54 times)

#### wireless info END ############

Comment: See if it will find wifi if it is closer to the router

Answer (score 0):

I have Asus zenbook and the wireless works ok. Note that the wireless interface can appear as wlp2sX instead of wlanX when you use ifconfig -a.
You could try the following:

### 1. Get details about available WiFi networks:

$ sudo iwlist wlp2sX scan

### 2. Add network to the known wifi networks:

Edit the file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

Go to the bottom of the file and add the following:

network={
    ssid="your_ssid"
    psk="your_password"
}

NOTE! Remember the quotation marks (") and the last closing bracket (}).

### 3. Bring the Wifi interface up

$ sudo ifdown wlp2sX; sudo ifup wlp2sX

Hope this helps!

Comment: My wifi is already in the network list. Would this solution help again?